# What's does 仮歌 mean here?

Tags: translation

I'm having trouble understanding this rock star's tweet:

たまーに仮歌とか流れてくる笑RT @maoloveai: @mao_sid シド率はどのくらいですか(^0^)？

What is 仮歌？

What does that tweet say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 口でメロディーを歌うデモテープの場合は適当な言葉をあてがうことが多く、この状態のものを「仮歌」と呼び、仮歌を専門に歌う「仮歌シンガー」と呼ばれる歌手もいる

[from wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%87%E3%83%A2%E3%83%86%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97)

So I'm not 100% sure but they are probably talking about some early prototype of a song which still uses some temporary random lyrics for the time being.

Comment: 仮歌 (which I think is read as かりうた but I am not sure) sometimes already has (tentative) lyrics.  For example, in [this blog](http://iida.tv/blog/post-26.html), the author says that he did 詞先の作曲 (adding music to lyrics) and talks about recording 仮歌, so the song already has lyrics.  I do not know if this usage is common or not, though.

Comment: This is correct. A singer may request music from a composer with the intent of adding in his/her own lyrics later, and on occasion the demo track will arrive with a temporary vocal track solely for the purpose of showing how the composer imagines the lyrics will fit with the melody. This track is later thrown away after the singer records his/her own vocal track. In English, the closest term is probably "scratch [vocal] track".